# How do I stop onClick from rendering when the page renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I am currently using React with Gatsby and Material UI Buttons. I want the button that was most recently pressed to have a certain state. Currently, When I run my code, all 4 of my buttons are getting disabled because the one that was most recently clicked gets disabled. Other posts have said that binding was the problem, but I am already doing it here. What can I do to make this work as expected?

This is the code for the function that I wrote in the class:

```
constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
          pressed: [true, false, false, false],
          current: 0
      }
    }


getButtonState = location => {
    return this.state.pressed[location]
}

changeButtonState(location){
        const newState = this.state.pressed.slice() //copy the array
        newState[location] = true //execute the manipulations
        newState[this.state.current] = false
        this.setState({
            pressed: newState,
            current: location
        })
    }
```

This is the code for my button render:

```
render() {
   return(
     <div>
       <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" disabled={ () => this.getButtonState(0) } 
        onClick={() => {this.changeButtonState(0)}} style={{ borderRadius: 25, margin: 4 }}>All</Button>
       <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" disabled={ () => this.getButtonState(1) } 
         onClick={() => {this.changeButtonState(1)}} style={{ borderRadius: 25, margin: 4 }}>Mechanical</Button>
       <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" disabled={ () => this.getButtonState(2)} 
         onClick={() => {this.changeButtonState(2)}} style={{ borderRadius: 25, margin: 4  }}>Software</Button>
       <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" disabled={ () => this.getButtonState(3)} 
         onClick={() => {this.changeButtonState(3)}} style={{ borderRadius: 25, margin: 4  }}>Design</Button>
     </div>
   )
 }
```

What can I do??

Comment: What is the implementation of `Button`? assuming it lines up with a normal `button`, `disabled` is a boolean, not a function. Your function assignment will always evaluate to `true` meaning all buttons are disabled.

Comment: @BrianThompson The implementation of Button is the Material UI Button, and can be found here [link] (https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#button)

Comment: It could be more helpful if you add some more information of code or maybe a codesandbox.io demo so as to get your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting disable equal to a function but it accepts a boolean value.
This `disable= {() => this.getButtonState(0)}` should be `disabled={this.getButtonState(0)}`

You don't need to worry about event handling and binding this, because you don't need to pass a function

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!